# Serve images based on string form url with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve uploaded images via Nginx, so the Express-App can concentrate on other tasks. In this case the usual alias-approach seems not quite enough though.

### Files/Images on Harddrive:

The Images are renamed and stored under randomized strings. This is how the files-folder looks on the harddrive:

```
/srv/expressap/uploads/files/images

33134ijnas9d8.jpg
81j917asdlkas.png
ja982p1031la0.png
...
```

### Requested Urls to get Images

```
htto://www.project.com/files/images/33134ijnas9d8/puppy.jpg
htto://www.project.com/files/images/81j917asdlkas/mittens.png
htto://www.project.com/files/images/ja982p1031la0/snuggles.png
```

#### Question

This - obviously - doesn't work since 'puppy.jpg' is not the actual filename the image '33134ijnas9d8.jpg'

```
location /files/images {
   alias /srv/expressap/uploads/files/images
}
```

How would the location-section look like to serve the actual image under the given url?

How to
1) get the id-string from the url?

2) Serve the image based on the id-string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regexp for this, Nginx [supports](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) them.

```
location ~* ^/files/images/(\w+)/.+\.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
   alias /srv/expressap/uploads/files/images/$1.$2;
}
```

`~*` - regexp case-insensitive modifier

`(\w+)` - any word-like sequence without spaces

`$1`, `$2` - references to the matching groups in brackets

Details about using regexps with `alias` [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

So, you mostly need to extract some parts of the `$uri` by means of a regexp and pass them to the `alias` directive.
You may test your regexp [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZJTQzp/2), though I didn't test it with Nginx, implementation may differ.